# Multiple frontends (clients) same backend

Tags: frontend, backend

May be this pattern may sound old but how do we achieve a scenario in where we want to have a single backend (database), single business logic layer and have multiple frontends ? desktop, web and  mobile ?

Something like modern apps have - gmail, facebook, evernote etc. 
Can this be done by writing microservices and having these different clients consuming it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create REST API for back-end containing business logic for data getting or submission. Type of data that is used for intercommunication between front-end and back-end can be JSON type.
Types of requests that you should support in your REST API should be:
GET requests should be used to return data from database,
POST requests should be used to submit data in database,
PUT/PATCH requests should be used to update data in database,
DELETE requests should be used to delete data in database

Answer (score 1):

Yes it absolutely can be done.
Even if you have the back-end and front-end in the same framework at the end of the day when a request is made by a client from a different location to a remote server anyway, so once that initial response has been sent, it does not make much of a difference weather you have separate apps or one monolith app.

If the code base is small, you could dump multiple apps on the same machine.

This is what I am doing for a couple of projects which are not huge,
I have one PHP backend and 2 front-ends one for Admin and the other for the User